# Put two tables side by side in the same page

Tags: tables, tabulary

I tried put two tables in the same page. I read in the Internet that I can make this using the minipage. I use minipage but the two tables still in pages differents, not side by side.
The piece of code that I used is:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{mathtools,float,geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs,array,tabularx,threeparttablex}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
\begin{minipage}{.2\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\toprule Tempo (s) & Per\'{i}odo (s)\\
\midrule 0,9509 & 1,3645\\
\hline 2,3153 & 1,3644\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[H]
\begin{minipage}{.2\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\toprule Tempo (s) & Velocidade (m/s)\\
\midrule 0,2733 & 5,3763\\
\hline 0,9496 & 5,3763\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\end {table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Put the minipages into a single `table` environment.

Comment: @cfr How I do that? Do you want me to do a only one table?

Comment: One `table`. Two `minipage`s. Two `tabular`s.

Comment: @cfr But I used in this code two `minipages` (I begin and end two `minipages`). I don't understand. Can you explain your ideia better for me, please?

Comment: @cfr I try to make your suggestion but now the first table is on the other table, and the table which is below go out of the page.

Comment: That's because `.2\textwidth` is too little. See below.

Comment: @cfr thanks for the demonstration. I make this code like you, but my data is more big that I put in the code when I wrote the question because not fit. Now, the two tables are side by side, but the biggest table are on the footer. I can't read the data of this table, because the letters are overlapping.

Comment: @cfr I put 0,4 like you but this appears the same effect that I wrote in my last comment.

Comment: You can increase `0.4` a bit, but if the total width of the two tables exceeds your total `\textwidth` then you cannot make them fit side-by-side without either making the tables smaller (smaller font, less content etc.) or making the `\textwidth` bigger (bigger paper, smaller margins etc.). Or you can rotate the entire page or the tables for landscape mode. But I don't know what you mean about the footer or how tall the tables are, so this may not help.

Answer (score 4):

This is the idea:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
  \begin{table}[H]
    \begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}
      \centering
      \begin{tabular}{cc}
        \toprule Tempo (s) & Per\'{i}odo (s)\\
        \midrule 0,9509 & 1,3645\\
        2,3153 & 1,3644\\
        \bottomrule
      \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}
      \centering
      \begin{tabular}{cc}
        \toprule Tempo (s) & Velocidade (m/s)\\
        \midrule 0,2733 & 5,3763\\
        0,9496 & 5,3763\\
        \bottomrule
      \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: double trouble]